# Xcode build command equivalent in python

Tags: python, python-3.4, xcrun

I tried the equivalent of :

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v  "$APP_OUTPUT_DIR"/"$PRODUCT_NAME".app -o "$APP_OUTPUT_DIR"/"$PLIST_IPA_NAME".ipa -embed "$PROVISONING_PROFILE_PATH" "OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS=--keychain $TEAMCITY_RUN_SCRIPT_LOCATION/$TEAMCITY_KEYCHAIN"
```

in python3.4 using subprocess as :

```
value = '/usr/bin/xcrun'
cmd = [value1]
cmd += [" -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v " + app_output_directory + '/' + product_name + '.app']
cmd += [" -o " + app_output_directory + '/' + product_name + '.ipa']
cmd += [" -embed " + provisioning_profile_path]
cmd += [' --keychain ' + value]
print(cmd)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Am I doing it correct. If not, please give a solution.

EDIT: The error is like

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "\ -sdk\ iphoneos\ PackageApplication\ -v\ /Users/NAME/Desktop/iOS/build/Sun\ Risers.app", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Comment: could you provide a print of cmd before you call `subprocess.call(cmd)`

Comment: @wiseveri: `['/usr/bin/xcrun', ' -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v /Users/NAME/Desktop/iOS/build/Sun Risers.app', ' -o /Users/NAME/Desktop/iOS/build/Sun Risers.ipa', ' -embed /Users/NAME/Desktop/iOS/Risers.mobileprovision', ' --keychain /Applications/BuildScripts/sun.keychain']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass every command line argument as a different list item, like that:

```
value = '/usr/bin/xcrun'
cmd = [value]
cmd.append('-sdk iphoneos PackageApplication')
cmd.append('-v' + app_output_directory + '/' + product_name + '.app')
...
subprocess.call(cmd)
```